# Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ has no composition series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, integers, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups

Please, read the whole post before trying to answer.

**Remark**: here $\subset$ means "strict inclusion".

I need to prove that the group $\mathbb{Z}$ has no composition series. That is, no normal series of subgroups $d_i\mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$\{ 0 \} = d_0 \mathbb{Z} \subset ... \subset d_n \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z},$$

for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, all its subgroups are normal, so any series of subgroups is normal. Let us have a series of a finite length

$$\{ 0 \} = d_0 \mathbb{Z} \subset ... \subset d_n \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z},$$

of some subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ (such that inclusions are well-defined).

We need to prove that $\frac{d_{i+1}\mathbb{Z}}{d_i\mathbb{Z}}$ is not simple for any subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $d_i \mathbb{Z} \subset d_{i+1} \mathbb{Z}$.

**First question. Is it the right way to reformulate the task?**

Next: $\frac{d_{i+1}\mathbb{Z}}{d_i\mathbb{Z}}$ is nor simple if there is a normal subgroup $\frac{k\mathbb{Z}}{d_i\mathbb{Z}}$ of $\frac{d_{i+1}\mathbb{Z}}{d_i\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $d_i \mathbb{Z} \subset k \mathbb{Z} \subset d_{i+1} \mathbb{Z}$.

**Second question. is is true that $K/H$ is normal in $P/H$ iff $K$ is normal in $P$?**

I suppose yes, but would like to hear the confirmation.

If the statement above is true, than it suffices to show that
$$\forall \ \ n,m  \in \mathbb{N}: n \mathbb{Z} \subset m \mathbb{Z} \ \ \exists k \in \mathbb{N}: n \mathbb{Z} \subset k \mathbb{Z} \subset m \mathbb{Z}.$$

**Third question. How can we show it?**

Assuming the answer to the previous questions is "yes".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: every proper nonzero subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$

About your points.

A quotient $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ *can* be simple, precisely when $a$ divides $b$ and $b/a$ is prime.

It is true that, assuming $K$ is a subgroup of $P$ and $H$ is normal in $P$, then $K/H$ is normal in $P/H$ if and only if $K$ is normal in $P$. This is unimportant here, because we're in an abelian group.

Comment: So, if $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ is simple, why it means that $a|b$ What is it doesn't? And what is $\frac{b}{a}$ is not prime? Could you give some hints? And I don't see how $d\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$ helps us at the moment.

Comment: @Jxt921 In order that $b\mathbb{Z}\subseteq a\mathbb{Z}$ you need $a$ divides $b$; otherwise, $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't make sense. Since $d\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}$, for $d\ne0$, it's impossible that $\mathbb{Z}$ has a simple subgroup. Of course, a group having a composition series has at least a simple subgroup.

Comment: $b \mathbb{Z} \subset a \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow \forall z_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \ \ \exists x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}: \ \ bz_1 = az_2$. Is this the consequence of "$z_1 = 1$, then there must exist an integer $z_2: b = az_2$" ? Does the converse( $a|b \Rightarrow b \mathbb{Z} \subset a \mathbb{Z}$ ) also holds?

Comment: @Jxt921 If $b\mathbb{Z}\subseteq a\mathbb{Z}$, then $b\in a\mathbb{Z}$, so $b=ax$ for some $x$. Yes, also the converse holds.

Comment: Thank you. I still have two questions for you. 1)Why $\frac{b}{a}$ have to be prime? 2)I got it that if group has a composition series, than for some subgroup $d \mathbb{Z}$ the quotient subgroup $d \mathbb{Z}/ \{ 0 \} \cong d \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But how do we know ''simplicity" is invariant under isomorphism?

Comment: @Jxt921 If $a\mid b$ and $b/a=k$, then $a\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ (try it). Consider $d>1$; then $d\mathbb{Z}$ is a proper nonzero subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ and it has a proper nonzero subgroup itself, being isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5):

Your first reformulation of the problem is not correct; it suffices to show that *one* of the quotients is not simple, not all of them.

It is true that $K/H$ is normal in $P/H$ if and only if $K$ is normal in $P$. But you don't need this fact because all groups concerned are abelian, so all subgroups in all quotients are normal.

The last statement you wish to prove is false; take $m=1$ and $n=2$. Here's another approach:

---

Suppose there exists a composition series
$$\{0\}=d_0\Bbb{Z}\subset\ldots\subset d_n\Bbb{Z}=\Bbb{Z}.$$
The fact that $d_{i+1}\Bbb{Z}/d_i\Bbb{Z}$ is simple means it is of prime order, so $d_i=p_id_{i+1}$ for some prime $p_i$. Then $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}p_i=d_0=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you please tell why $d_{i+1} \mathbb{Z}/ d_i \mathbb{Z}$ has to have a prime order to be simple, and why $| d_{i+1} \mathbb{Z} / d_i \mathbb{Z} | = \frac{d_{i+1}}{d_i}$?

Comment: The group $d_{i+1}\Bbb{Z}/d_i\Bbb{Z}$ is cyclic of order $\tfrac{d_i}{d_{i+1}}$, because the map
$$\Bbb{Z}/\tfrac{d_i}{d_{i+1}}\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ d_{i+1}\Bbb{Z}/d_i\Bbb{Z}:\ k\ \longmapsto\ d_{i+1}k,$$
is an isomorphism. If $g$ is a generator of a cyclic group of order $n$ and $d$ is a divisor of $n$, then $g^{d}$ generates a subgroup of order $\tfrac{n}{d}$. So $\Bbb{Z}/\tfrac{d_{i+1}}{d_i}\Bbb{Z}$ has no nontrivial (normal) subgroups if and only if $\tfrac{d_i}{d_{i+1}}$ has no nontrivial divisors.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose $\mathbf{Z}$ has a composition series. Then

$$\mathbf{Z}=m_0{\mathbf{Z}} \supseteq m_1{\mathbf{Z}} ... \supseteq m_k{\mathbf{Z}} \supseteq \{e\}$$
where each $m_{i} | m_{i+1}$ and $m_{i+1}\mathbf{Z} \unlhd m_{i}\mathbf{Z}$
and $ m_{i}\mathbf{Z}/m_{i+1}\mathbf{Z}$ is simple

Then $ m_{k}\mathbf{Z}$ is also simple
We know subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Therefore $ m_{k}\mathbf{Z}$ is generated by some element say $b \in  m_{k}\mathbf{Z}$ i.e. $$m_{k}\mathbf{Z}=<b>$$
now observe that $$<b^2> \unlhd <b>$$
which is a contradiction as $ m_{k}\mathbf{Z}$ was simple.
Therefore  $\mathbf{Z}$ has a no composition series

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that modules with composition series are Artinian?
If so, that is another way to dispatch the problem since $\mathbb Z$ is not an Artinian module, of course.