# There can be two different infinite composition series of $\Bbb Z$ that do not share any factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This Math SE thread ([$\mathbb{Z}$ has no composition series. Need an assistance in some questions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839640/mathbbz-has-no-composition-series-need-an-assistance-in-some-questions)) gives a proof for the fact that $\Bbb Z$ has no *finite* composition series.

However, my professor remarked in class that one can even find two different *infinite* composition series for $\Bbb Z$, that do not share any factors. Could someone give me some hints on how to prove this? I haven't dealt with infinite composition series before.

Comment: The statement in the title (which is false) is different from the statement in the post (which is true). Also, usually composition series are required to be finite by definition; I'll assume by "infinite composition series" you mean an infinite decreasing exhaustive filtration. Hint: build a composition series whose factors are all $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and a composition series whose factors are all $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Edit: the title has been corrected.

Comment: I've edited the title now. Thanks for the hints; I will try to think about it further. :)

Comment: I think your professor should stick to standard usage, which is that composition series are finite by definition. Extending this notion to infinite series is complicated and depends on your choice of totally ordered set as indexing set.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure what an "infinite composition series" is, but I reckon what your prof may have had in mind is two descending chains of subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ like
$$\Bbb Z\supset2\Bbb Z\supset4\Bbb Z\supset\cdots\supset2^n\Bbb Z\supset\cdots$$
and
$$\Bbb Z\supset3\Bbb Z\supset9\Bbb Z\supset\cdots\supset3^n\Bbb Z\supset\cdots.$$